# How to make two classes to work together and return it as JSON

Tags: java, json, class, gson

My plan is to make a JSON results by my database. What I mean is that I have made a Class where I connect to a API (etc. TMDB) and take the information I need.

```
public class MovieDataBase {
   Attributes att = new Attributes(); //A klass where I have setter-getter 
                         //methods for titel, overview, vote, release.

      public String searchMovie(String filmtitel) {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response;
             try {
                 response =  Unirest.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie")
                          .queryString("api_key", "123")
                          .queryString("query", filmtitel)
                          .asJson();

            JsonNode json = response.getBody();
            JSONObject envelope = json.getObject();
            JSONArray results = envelope.getJSONArray("results");

        filmtitel += att.title = results.getJSONObject(0).getString("title");
        filmtitel += att.release = results.getJSONObject(0).getString("release_date");
        filmtitel += att.vote = results.getJSONObject(0).getInt("vote_average");
        filmtitel += att.overview = results.getJSONObject(0).getString("overview");

          return filmtitel

         }
catch (JSONException e) {
```

and I also have a get method where I want to create a JSON construction of the program to easier use it in the future (for html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     setPort(8080);
     Youtube yt = new Youtube();
     MovieDataBase mdb = new MovieDataBase();

        get("/search/:movie", (req, res) ->  {
          String movie = req.queryParams(":movie");
          String movies = mdb.searchMovie(movie);
          String json = att.title + att.release + att.vote + att.vote + att.overview

           json = gson.toJson(json);

           return json
});
```

This did not work. I'm getting a null when I'm running it, not a error but only a null. So I have to combine  `String movies = mdb.searchMovie(movie);` with the String Json and then make it look like a json, but I don't know if that's right.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Done and edited! Is it better now?

Comment: Thank you @mikeTheLiar !

Comment: @WeInThis not a problem. Your enthusiasm is endearing.